# Extract .hex from ATtiny45 using Arduino

Tags: attiny, avrdude

As it is possible to program a ATtiny45 using Arduino as ISP Programmer, is there a way to backup an ATtiny45 program to a .hex file using Arduino?

Comment: You'll have to use the commandline for that. Inside the arduino program folder there is another executable called `avrdude`. You need to call something like `avrdude -pattiny45 -cstk500v1 -Uflash:r:filename.hex:i`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the lock bits on the device haven't been set, sure. Simply prepare the Arduino for ArduinoISP, hook up the ATtiny45, and perform a read using AVRDUDE instead of a write (`-U flash:r:foo.hex:i`).

Comment: Sorry, totally missed your mention of that.